# What is the degree of a variety after the Segre embedding?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Construction:** Let $k$ be a field and let $X:Proj(S) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^N_k$ be a projective variety. The degree $deg_S(X)$ is defined in terms of the graded ring $S$ and the Hilbert polynomial $P_S(t)$ of $S$, hence $deg_S(X)$ depends on the embedding $X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^N_k$. The Segre embedding

$$\psi_{n,m}:Y:=\mathbb{P}^n_k \times_k \mathbb{P}^m_k \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{nm+n+m}_k$$

is a closed embedding and given a product $X:=X_1\times_k X_2 \subseteq Y$ we may ask the following question: What is $deg(\psi_{n,m}(X))$?

**Partial answer:** I just finished exercise about calculating the degree of Segre variety $\Sigma_{m,n}$ which is $(m + n) \choose n$. I was thinking about generalization of this exercise. Suppose we start with a variety $X_1 \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ and $X_2 \subset \mathbb{P}^m$. We have the Segre embedding $\Sigma : \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{(n + 1)(m + 1) - 1}$. Suppose that $deg(X_1) = x_1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and $deg(X_2) = x_2$ in $\mathbb{P}^m$. What is the degree of $X_1 \times X_2$ in $\mathbb{P}^{(n + 1)(m + 1) - 1}$.

Comment: you should include your calculations to stop the "close" votes. The question is interesting for students in algebraic geometry but on this site people tend to vote to close such question for unknown reasons.

Comment: @hm2020 Thank you! I am new to mathstackexchange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quewstion:** "What is the degree of $X_1 \times X_2$ in $\mathbb{P}^{(n + 1)(m + 1) - 1}$."

**Answer/reduction:** There is a formula (Hartshorne, Ex.IV.3.3.2) saying that if $\phi:X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a closed immersion corresponding to a linebundle $L(D)$ and if $m=1$ you get $deg(\phi(X))=deg(L(D))$.

More generally if $dim(X)=m$ you get the formula

$$deg(X)=deg([X])=\int_{\mathbb{P}^n_k} c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))^m \cap [X].$$

The product $\cap$ is defined in the Chow group $CH^*(\mathbb{P}^n_k)$. The first Chern class $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))$ and its "powers" acts on the Chow group.

The Segre embedding is the embedding

$$\phi: \mathbb{P}^n_k \times_k \mathbb{P}^m_k \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^N_k$$
corresponding to $\mathcal{O}(1,1):=p^*\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes q^*\mathcal{O}(2)$ and if $X:=X_1\times_k X_2$ and if $L(D):=\mathcal{O}(1,1)_X$ you get

$$deg(\phi(X))=D^m.$$

This reduces the problem to calculating this degree/intersection. Are you able to do this?

**Note:** If $k$ is algebraically closed and if $D:=\sum_i n_i [Y_i]$ with $Y_i \subseteq X$ an integral subscheme, we define $deg(D):=\sum_i n_i deg(Y_i)$ (HH.Ex.II.6.2), hence you must calculate the divisor $D$ corresponding to $L$.

**Example:** If $C:=\mathbb{P}^1_k$ and $L:=\mathcal{O}(d)$ it follows the corresponding divisor $D$ is $D=\sum_{i=1}^r n_i[P_i]$ with $P_i \in C(k)$ a closed point and $\sum_i n_i=d$. Hence $deg(L):= deg(D):= \sum_i n_i=d$. The divisor $D$ corresponds to the $d$-uple embedding

$$v_d: C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^d_k$$

and hence $deg(v_d(C))=d$. If $d=2$ it follows $v_d(C)=Z(F)$ with $F:=x_0x_2-x_1^2$, and hence $deg(Z(F))=deg(F)=2$. For $d \geq 3$ it follows $v_d(C)$ is no longer a hypersurface hence the calculation does not follow from HH.CH.I.7.

https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=degree+of+a+divisor

**Note:** A more elementary approach using the "projective bundle formula" is outlined as an exercise in Harris "Algebraic geometry - a first course" (Ex. 19.2, pg 240).

You write the fundamental class

$$[X]= \sum_i d_i[\mathbb{P}^i_k\times_k \mathbb{P}^{l-i}_k]$$

and the formula says

$$(*) deg(\phi(X))= \sum_i \binom{m}{i}d_i.$$

**Note:** If $k$ is the complex number field there is the Chern character isomorphism

$$Ch: K_0(\mathbb{P}(E^*))_{\mathbb{Q}} \cong H_*(\mathbb{P}(E^*),\mathbb{Q})$$

and there is the projective bundle formula

$$K_0(\mathbb{P}(E^*)) \cong K_0(X)[t]/(t^{e+1})$$

where $rk(E)=e+1$. Hence if $E:=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_k}^{m+1}$ it follows

$$K_0(\mathbb{P}^n_k \times_k \mathbb{P}^m_k)_{\mathbb{Q}} \cong 
 \mathbb{Q}[t_1,t_2]/(t_1^{n+1}, t_2^{m+1}).$$

There is an equality of classes $t_1^{i}t_2^{j}=[\mathbb{P}^{n-i}_k \times_k \mathbb{P}^{m-j}_k]$

and you must express the fundamental class $[X_1\times_k X_2]$ in this basis. In the Grothendieck group you write

$$[X_1\times_k X_2]:= \sum_{i,j} d_{i,j}t_1^it_2^j$$

and use $(*)$. The numbers $d_{i,j}$ should be integer functions of the numbers $x_1,x_2$.

**Remark:** I have not done this exercise but it is a good place to start.

Comment: Hartshorne doesn't say what you claim in example IV.3.3.2: this treats only the case of curves, not general varieties.

Comment: @KReiser - I'm saying that for $m=1$ this may be found in Hartshorne.